# Recursive function for Menu and Submenu until the last child is coming in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, recursion

I've a MySQL Table Module which contains my Menu and Sub-menu both.

Also I've  created a relationship of Module table with same table itself like the Primary key of Module table(`id`) is the foreign key of Module Table it self(`parent_id`). Now I want a recursive function which will fetch all the modules as well as sub modules in a tree format in Django.

```
Menu-1 +    
    Sub-menu-1
      | 
    Sub-Menu-2
      |-Sub-Menu-2.1
      |-Sub-Menu-2.2
```

parent_id of **Sub-menu-1** will be the primary key of **Menu-1** and parent_id of **Sub-Menu-2.1** will be the primary key of **Sub-menu-1**.

Attached is the structire of my table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO6qH.png

I'm new to Python and Djnago.. Can somebody help and do let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're re-inventing the wheel. I'd suggest using a third party package such as [django-treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard)

This will both give you the model fields required and an easy interface to recurse through them.